# Derivatives of p-adic L-functions of modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, l-functions, iwasawa-theory

Let $f$ be a eigen-newform and $p$ is a good prime for $f$. We know that the $p$-adic $L$-function of $f$ interpolates the complex $L$-values of $f$ when evaluated at Dirichlet characters.

My question is, what about the derivative? If we look at the derivative of the $p$-adic $L$-function, does it interpolate the derivative of the complex $L$-function?

Comment: This is actually a more reasonable question that what it may look like at first. So I would vote against closing. Assume trivial nebentype. For $L(f,1)$, it is non-zero, then there is a formula connecting complex and $p$-adic $L'(f,1)$ thanks to the functional equation like in https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06428 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.02953. When it vanishes to order 1, the complex and $p$-adic Gross-Zagier formulae give a link. Otherwise they are both zero. Now, I have not thought about if something like this works for the twist by characters to give a link for the derivatives.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich It is known by Rohrlich that there are only finitely many Dirichlet characters of $p$-power conductor such that $L(f,\chi,1)=0$. This tells us there are only finitely many values $L'(f,\chi,1)$ to interpolate, so the naive procedure won't work. Of course they may be more clever ways to do the interpolation.

Comment: @François My comment suggest that it could be that one can (if one really wants) interpolate $L'(f,\chi,1)$ even when $L(f,\chi,1)\neq 0$ because there could be a relation between the two values. This is true for the trivial character.

Comment: @Chris I see, I guess you refer to your recent article on the sub-leading term of the L-function. By the way I forgot that $L(f,\chi,1) \neq 0$ does not imply $L'(f,\chi,1)=0$ even for the trivial character... This is true for the completed L-function $\Lambda(f,1)$ in the case $f$ is self-dual but not for $L(f,1)$.